# Non-blocking TCP server with .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, async-await, tcplistener

I need to implement a Windows service with a tcp listener to listen indefinitely and process the data feed coming from a tcp port and I'm looking for any samples using .NET 4.5 async features.

The only [sample](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/tcp-servers-net-scenario-4-non-blocking-servers-net-45) I have found so far is:

```
class Program
{
    private const int BufferSize = 4096;
    private static readonly bool ServerRunning = true;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tcpServer = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 9000);
        try
        {
            tcpServer.Start();
            ListenForClients(tcpServer);
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to shutdown");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            tcpServer.Stop();
        }
    }

    private static async void ListenForClients(TcpListener tcpServer)
    {
        while (ServerRunning)
        {
            var tcpClient = await tcpServer.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            ProcessClient(tcpClient);
        }
    }

    private static async void ProcessClient(TcpClient tcpClient)
    {
        while (ServerRunning)
        {
            var stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
            var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, BufferSize);
            var message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, amountRead);
            Console.WriteLine("Client sent: {0}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

As I'm relatevely new to this topic I wonder:

1. What improvements would you suggest to this code?
2. How to gracefully stop the listener (now it throws `ObjectDisposedException`).
3. Is there more advanced samples of .net tcp listener?

Comment: Most of this question isn't appropriate for SO. Read tutorials, and learn to transfer conceptual information from samples to different use cases. The only valid subquestion would be **2)**.

Comment: You could look into WCF Async method; WCF will allow you to communicate through TCP.

Comment: +1 @millimoose - The answer to the question "What improvements would you suggest to this code" is a) it depends on requirements and b) probably lots. Read more tutorials or consider using a network library rather than writing all of the network code yourself. I'm a developer for the network library http://www.networkcomms.net